# The Base-href/deploy-url parameters don't work as expected: paths aren't changed after building

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I use Angular 6

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>

<script src="./config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, the template of one component contains the img tag:

```
<img src="assets/spinner.gif">
```

In case I build it with the base-href/deploy-url parameters all works ok (base href, all css files and so on), except paths to config.js and assets/spinner.gif - angular-cli keeps these paths without changes.
How to solve this?

PS. I tried to use `"assets/spinner.gif"`, `"/assets/spinner.gif"`, `"./assets/spinner.gif"` - with the same result.

**PPS** Fragment of angular.json:

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project_name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/project_name",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/config.js",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Comment: Can you add your angular.json file please? specifically, the section under build -> options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the base-href parameter, it is important to always ensure that the path used ends with a trailing / and the paths in the HTML do not start with a / - so you need to end up with:

`<base href="/dir/"/>`

and

`<img src="assets/spinner.gif"/>`

Without the trailing /, the base will not be applied correctly.

Comment: I've added a fragment of `angular.json`. And it copies all necessary files to the output directory: config.js and gif image.

Comment: Looks correct - can you sanity check that if you browse to /assets/spinner.gif and /config.js in the browser, you do actually get the files loaded?

Comment: I use IIS with virtual directory: the whole app is accessible by `http://localhost/dir`. And I am able to access to this GIF by the use of `http://localhost/dir/assets/spinner.gif`. But the problem is that the angular tries to use `http://localhost/assets/spinner.gif` to access this picture.

Comment: As you've got the base set to /, I would think that is expected and correct... if you're running it in the /dir/ folder, I would think the base should be set to /dir/. Check in the network tab of Chrome dev tools when loading the site and see what exact URLs it is trying to load from.

Comment: I did it already, all works fine, except it requested these two files without `dir` with the appropriate 404 result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178014/discussion-between-don-tomato-and-mark-hughes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent at least several hours for nothing before your help!

Comment: Welcome @DonTomato :) It was an interesting problem!